# Get top three highest salaries from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

List of dictionaries are given, each dictionary has name and salary. Need to get top three employees with highest salary

```
sample_list = [

{'name': 'John', 'salary': 6000},

{'name': 'Jane', 'salary': 8000},

{'name': 'Tom', 'salary': 7500},

{'name': 'Emma', 'salary': 8000},

{'name': 'Emily', 'salary': 3000},

{'name': 'Dan', 'salary': 500},

{'name': 'Brad', 'salary': 400}

]

top_three_employees = 3

expected_output = ['Jane', 'Tom', 'Emma']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Any ideas? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to achieve using the `sorted` method to get the data arranged in salary order. You then just need to iterate over that and select the names of the first three entries.

e.g.

```
sample_list = [
    {'name': 'John', 'salary': 6000},
    {'name': 'Jane', 'salary': 8000},
    {'name': 'Tom', 'salary': 7500},
    {'name': 'Emma', 'salary': 8000},
    {'name': 'Emily', 'salary': 3000},
    {'name': 'Dan', 'salary': 500},
    {'name': 'Brad', 'salary': 400}
]

# Sorting the list of dictionaries by 'salary' in descending order
sorted_list = sorted(sample_list, key=lambda x: x['salary'], reverse=True)

# Getting the names of the top 3 earners
top_3_names = [entry['name'] for entry in sorted_list[:3]]

print(top_3_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to sort the list of dictionaries using the salary of each as the key:

```
sample_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['salary'], reverse=True)
```

After that you only have to return the first x (in your case 3) values from the dict:

```
top_employee_number = 3
top_names = [employee['name'] for employee in sample_list[:top_employee_number]]`
```

That's basically it!